# How can I get the DOMRange-style offset within a DOM node for a given mouse (or document) location?

Tags: javascript, dom

I know how to determine which DOM nodes intersect an absolute position. But say that's a text node. How can I determine the offset within the text node corresponding to that location? I'd like to construct a DOMRange from a known position to that position.

Comment: Pretty sure that's not possible, at least cross-browser compatibly, but would love to hear otherwise...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step would be to find all `Elements` that intersect the position. You should use the [`Element.getBoundingClientRect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getBoundingClientRect) method to do this. You can then easily get all of the `Text` nodes that sit within that `Element`. The hard part is to figure out what text within those `Text` nodes are within those bounds. You can start with the [`Element.getClientRects`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getClientRects) to get lines of text within that `Element`. Here's a [great example](https://developer.mozilla.org/@api/deki/files/4666/=getClientRects-example.html).

You'll then want to construct a `Range` object, changing the `startOffset` and `endOffset` appropriately. You can use the `getClientRects` method on the `Range` object, too.

Comment: Thank you: `getClientRects()` was the key. I've got an initial implementation working that performs a binary search over the space of valid DOMRanges, recursing down the node tree until it hits a leaf or a TEXT/comment/CDATA node. I'll post code when I get a chance to clean it up and so on.

Comment: I have published my implementation at https://github.com/andymatuschak/DOMNodeAndChildOffsetContainingViewportLocation.